# mysqli query on LAMP stack not returning errors, but not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, lamp

So I am taking my site live but I had to switch over from MAMP to LAMP and am having some (well, lots) trouble with this query. At this point, I have to to where the error messages are blank but I am still returning 0 rows. When I put the query directly in sql, it runs fine. I have not used any of these variables previously on the page, so I don't think there is any interference with other variables.

```
$active=1;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, gender, homelat, homelng, salt FROM users WHERE username='?' AND active='?'");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $username, $active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $xusername, $xpassword, $gender, $homelat, $homelng, $salt);
echo "running";
if (!$stmt) {header('Location: login.php'); die();}
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
    $_SESSION['error'] = ($homelat. htmlspecialchars($stmt->error). htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error). "number 2 Incorrect username and password combination, please try to log in again");
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Sincere thanks for the help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You dont have to put single quotes around your question marks

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I've been tinkering with those.

Comment: My answer was wrong since num_rows and num_rows() are both fine as im reading now in the php doc, how does your $mysqli look like?

Comment: Try adding $stmt->fetch(); after $stmt->store_results(); and see if that works

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the fetch did it, and I also added a store_results(). I got it to return a row but but have one more bug to go. I really appreciate the help.